# Is there a way to correctly concatenate three arbitrary XPath expressions to result in a new valid XPath expression?

Tags: xpath, expression

Is there a way to correctly concatenate three arbitrary XPath expressions to result in a new valid XPath expression?

Comment: @user488963: To answer this, XPath expression examples are needed.

Comment: .//a[@class='no-hover hint']/b/text() .//a[@class='no-hover hint-2']/b/text() .//a[@class='no-hover hint'-3]/b/text() there is three expressions

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for many examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**: The OP has indicated in a comment that the three expressions select text nodes.

In this case using the union operator (`|`) seems most appropriate.

---

> Is there a way to correctly
>   concatenate three arbitrary XPath
>   expressions to result in a new valid
>   XPath expression?

**There are many possible ways to do this** and some of these may benefit from knowing the return type of the evaluation.

**One of the combinator that always "works"** (although maynot always be meaningful) is:

```
concat(Expr1, Expr2, Expr3)
```

**Other examples:**

```
number(Expr1) + number(Expr2) + number(Expr3)

boolean(Expr1) or boolean(Expr2) or boolean(Expr3)
```

**In case the expressions are guaranteed to select a node-set**, then this expression (the union of the node-sets) would also combine them:

```
Expr1 | Expr2 | Expr3
```

**In XPath 2.0 this expression should always work** (concatenation to a sequence of items):

```
Expr1 , Expr2 , Expr3
```

**or this one**:

```
  if(boolean(Expr1))
    then Expr2
    else Expr3
```

Comment: +1 Very good answer. Also, expression are in question's comments.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  If they are disjoint, then you place them together separated with an "or" statement.  If they are additive, then you can just do a (.net) Path.Combine() on them.